# How can I clear the media from the MediaPlayer when it has stopped

Tags: uwp, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I have a VideoView and in the code behind I create the MediaPlayer and a Media object to play a video. When I stop in the middle or it stops at the end, the last frame stays visible. When I load the same or another video in the same player, you see a glitch of that last frame. I want to clear the video from the player.

I've tried to set the Media property to null, call Dispose() on it first, but no luck. Frame stays there. Any tips how to achieve this?

I'm working with LibVLCSharp 3.3.1 and VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP 3.1.1.1 on UWP build 17134.

Comment: media.Dispose() can be called as soon as you don't need the media instance yourself, it just decrements a ref counter and can be called safely just after you have set the media on the player.

Comment: That said, this sounds like a bug of the UWP implementation, can you report a proper bug on code.videolan.org 's libvlcsharp repo?

Comment: Thanks. Created an issue.

Comment: Thanks, for future readers, the link is here : https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/issues/260 .

Answer (score 0):

you can change the opacity value of the MediaPlayerElement of your xaml

`<vlc:MediaPlayerELement x:Name="myvideo"`